# How to interpret Apple crash report

Tags: app-store, crash-reports

Please, help to understand Apple Crash report. It seems to me that the app even doesn't start, but I fail to repeat the bug. I have also added GoogleAnalytics to the app. Can the reason be in it?

```
{"app_name":"Cells","app_version":"1.0","bundleID":"avector.Cells","adam_id":918451381,"os_version":"iPhone OS 8.0 (12A365)","slice_uuid":"f203c691-c7ff-30c0-9dc0-2ac203b92004","share_with_app_devs":false,"build_version":"2.0","is_first_party":false,"bug_type":"109","name":"Cells"}
    Incident Identifier: 5D2C2326-720C-4456-BFFC-9D09AE4B82D0
    CrashReporter Key:   761270594f1e0a7b7ba69ad8bab60cd243da0a3d
    Hardware Model:      xxx
    Process:             Cells [1170]
    Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/6EABC83E-7A5E-40B8-8D61-9EE06530AF82/Cells.app/Cells
    Identifier:          avector.Cells
    Version:             2.0 (1.0)
    Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
    Parent Process:      launchd [1]

    Date/Time:           2014-09-19 15:27:20.980 -0700
    Launch Time:         2014-09-19 15:27:15.645 -0700
    OS Version:          iOS 8.0 (12A365)
    Report Version:      105

    Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
    Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
    Triggered by Thread:  0

    Last Exception Backtrace:
    (0x18485e084 0x1952b00e4 0x18485dd08 0x185662510 0x18478b8e0 0x1893e8f74 0x1892ef978 0x188fe0efc 0x188fe0e68 0x188fe7530 0x188fe4cd4 0x189055b38 0x189268ff0 0x18926b568 0x189269c00 0x18ca35640 0x184816360 0x184815468 0x184813668 0x184741664 0x18904b98c 0x189046984 0x1000bad10 0x19591ea08)

    Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
    Thread 0 Crashed:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000195a37270 __pthread_kill + 8
    1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000195ad5224 pthread_kill + 108
    2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001959aeb14 abort + 108
    3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000194a95414 abort_message + 112
    4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000194ab4b88 default_terminate_handler() + 300
    5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001952b03bc _objc_terminate() + 124
    6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000194ab1bb0 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 12
    7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000194ab1738 __cxa_rethrow + 140
    8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001952b0290 objc_exception_rethrow + 40
    9   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184741710 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 568
    10  UIKit                           0x000000018904b988 -[UIApplication _run] + 548
    11  UIKit                           0x0000000189046980 UIApplicationMain + 1484
    12  Cells                           0x00000001000bad0c 0x1000a8000 + 77068
    13  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000019591ea04 start + 0

    Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
    Thread 1:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000195a1cc94 kevent64 + 8
    1   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019590497c _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 272
    2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001958f74a0 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 48

    Thread 2:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000195a37c78 __workq_kernreturn + 8
    1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000195ad1390 _pthread_wqthread + 988
    2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000195ad0fa4 start_wqthread + 0

    Thread 3:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000195a37c78 __workq_kernreturn + 8
    1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000195ad1390 _pthread_wqthread + 988
    2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000195ad0fa4 start_wqthread + 0

    Thread 4:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000195a37c78 __workq_kernreturn + 8
    1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000195ad1390 _pthread_wqthread + 988
    2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000195ad0fa4 start_wqthread + 0

    Thread 5:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000195a37c78 __workq_kernreturn + 8
    1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000195ad1390 _pthread_wqthread + 988
    2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000195ad0fa4 start_wqthread + 0

    Thread 6 name:  GAIThread
    Thread 6:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000195a1ce7c mach_msg_trap + 8
    1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000195a1ccf4 mach_msg + 68
    2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184815804 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
    3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184813758 __CFRunLoopRun + 936
    4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184741660 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 392
    5   Foundation                      0x0000000185642200 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 312
    6   Foundation                      0x000000018569c8f4 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 92
    7   Cells                           0x00000001000bd0f8 0x1000a8000 + 86264
    8   Foundation                      0x000000018572a608 __NSThread__main__ + 1068
    9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000195ad3e7c _pthread_body + 160
    10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000195ad3dd8 _pthread_start + 156
    11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000195ad0fac thread_start + 0

    Thread 7:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000195a37c78 __workq_kernreturn + 8
    1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000195ad1390 _pthread_wqthread + 988
    2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000195ad0fa4 start_wqthread + 0

    Thread 8 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
    Thread 8:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000195a1ce7c mach_msg_trap + 8
    1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000195a1ccf4 mach_msg + 68
    2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184815804 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
    3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184813758 __CFRunLoopRun + 936
    4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184741660 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 392
    5   CFNetwork                       0x0000000184242054 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 436
    6   Foundation                      0x000000018572a608 __NSThread__main__ + 1068
    7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000195ad3e7c _pthread_body + 160
    8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000195ad3dd8 _pthread_start + 156
    9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000195ad0fac thread_start + 0

    Thread 9 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
    Thread 9:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000195a37498 __select + 8
    1   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018481b1fc __CFSocketManager + 656
    2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000195ad3e7c _pthread_body + 160
    3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000195ad3dd8 _pthread_start + 156
    4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000195ad0fac thread_start + 0

    Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x00000001700ec0b7
    x4: 0x0000000194ab5dfd   x5: 0x000000016fd57430   x6: 0x000000000000006e   x7: 0x0000000000000f80
    x8: 0x0000000008000000   x9: 0x0000000004000000  x10: 0x0000000000000200  x11: 0x0000000000000000
   x12: 0x0000000000000000  x13: 0x0000000000000000  x14: 0x0000000000000002  x15: 0x0000000000000000
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x0000000000000000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x00000001995f5310  x21: 0x00000001995ddce8  x22: 0x0000000170146b50  x23: 0x0000000195f32770
   x24: 0x0000000000000001  x25: 0x0000000170146b40  x26: 0x00000001995dc0a8  x27: 0x0000000000000001
   x28: 0x0000000000000000  fp: 0x000000016fd57390   lr: 0x0000000195ad5228
    sp: 0x000000016fd57370   pc: 0x0000000195a37270 cpsr: 0x00000000
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: same problem for me do you slove this?

Comment: I have created a new project and copied everything by parts. There were minor changes during the process, but I am sure, that the reason of the crash was related to project settings.